# How do I focus the playhead in the video sequencer/ dopesheet?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm using Blender to edit videos and I've run into a small productivity problem.

I'm constantly switching back and forth between the Dopesheet and the Video Sequencer editors and it would be really helpful if there was a shortcut to focus the playhead so I don't have to scroll around until I find it.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It is called *Go to Current Frame* the shortcut is  <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

[image]